# pass vector parameter to popup window

Tags: javascript

I need pass a vector like parameter to popup window
opened by javascript, I mean on this code to pen popup:

```
window.open("<my_site_url>?vector2popup=" +  js_vector, 'name popup', stile);
```

js_vector --> javascript is vector I need transfer to popup window

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only kind of data you can pass in a URL is a ([properly encoded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)) string.

Whatever the value of `js_vector` is (vector is not a standard JavaScript type and you haven't linked to any library documentation that might explain what you are talking about), you need to convert it to a string first.

[`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) **might** help with that.

Alternatively, capture the return value of `open`, wait for the document to load, then pass the variable via the object returned.